# Pandas random sample with remove

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aware of `DataFrame.sample()`, but how can I do this and also remove the sample from the dataset? (*Note: AFAIK this has nothing to do with sampling with replacement*)

For example here is **the essence** of what I want to achieve, this does not actually work:

```
len(df) # 1000

df_subset = df.sample(300)
len(df_subset) # 300

df = df.remove(df_subset)
len(df) # 700
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If your index is unique

```
df = df.drop(df_subset.index)
```

---

***example***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 2))
```

---

***sample***

```
df_subset = df.sample(2)
df_subset
```

[image]

---

***drop***

```
df.drop(df_subset.index)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway of using DataFrame. **pop**, to drop samples ? Because DataFrame. **pop** is generally used to pop columns.What if I transpose first my DF ?

Comment: @MMF great idea.  Yes, you can work just off of the transpose and do that.  You've inspired me to try something else.  If I can finish it before my next meeting, I'll post it here.

Comment: @MMF also, it appears that `pop` only accepts single column names.  Meaning, I can't pop multiples easily.

Comment: Yes I had the same problem. I popped multiple times, but then I guess it is not as efficient as df.drop()

Answer (score 15):

pandas [random sample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) :

```
train=df.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=200)
test=df.drop(train.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

CoPilot prompts:

```
test = df[~df.index.isin(df_subset.index)]
```