# ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mask, data-analysis

here is my code, no matters what I do I keep on getting the error and followed all the index related solutions, can anyone help me?

```
site = pd.read_csv('../data/survey_site.csv')
sampled = site.sample(n=1)

site = site.reset_index(drop=True)
sampled = sampled.reset_index(drop=True)

mask = site.mask(site['name'] == sampled['name'])
```

Comment: Try `mask = site.mask(site['name'] == sampled['name'].squeeze())`

Comment: Aaaaaaand it works...... If u could give any clues about why the problem appeared I would be very happy but seems to be with what `sample` returns. Thank you very very much. Also I don't know how to give u points for ur answer since this is the very first time I ask a question, If u could tell me how to I would be grateful

Comment: Sample returns a dataframe. Then sample['name'] is a series. Squeeze was an easy way to turn it to a scalar.

Comment: And isnt site['name'] the same as sampled['name'] since both are dataframes and both are requesting a column?

Comment: Omg piRSquared u had answered the question that involved my precise problem in an old thread, double thanks, this is precisely what I needed to do:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835021/pandas-random-sample-with-remove

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the comparison between `site['name']` and `sample['name']` is between two `pd.Series`.  You can bypass that by making one of them a scalar.  However, I noticed that you took a `sample` of length `1`.  I suspect you thought that when you took `sample['name']` that it would be a scalar value.  But instead it is a length one series.  So you just need to make is a scalar.

**Option 1**

```
mask = site.mask(site['name'] == sampled['name'].squeeze())
```

**Option 2**

```
mask = site.mask(site['name'] == sampled.loc[0, 'name'])
```