# Python 'Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects'

Tags: python, object, jupyter, series

I'm looking to append a column onto my csv file where it iterates through the csv then receieves the count of the symbol from another csv and appends it to that corresponding row.

```
#created the function that takes the input of the symbol passed 
def data_count(passed):

    x = prices.loc[(prices.symbol == 'A', 'close')].count()
    return(x)

securities['data freq'] == data_count(securities['Ticker symbol'])
securities
```

I believe the problem is the `x = prices.loc[(prices.symbol == 'A', 'close')].count()`, and in particular I think the problem might have to do with the `'A'` comparison.

I want to replace the `A` with the variable it recieves from iterating through the table, but when I try to do this my code throws the following error:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

RESPONSE:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-718d2fbf3ad8> in <module>()
      5     return(x)
      6 
----> 7 securities['data freq'] == data_count(securities['Ticker symbol'])
      8 securities

<ipython-input-77-718d2fbf3ad8> in data_count(passed)
      2 def data_count(passed):
      3     data = [passed]
----> 4     x = (prices.loc[(prices.symbol == passed, 'close')].count())
      5     return(x)
      6 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
    816             if not self._indexed_same(other):
    817                 msg = 'Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects'
--> 818                 raise ValueError(msg)
    819             return self._constructor(na_op(self.values, other.values),
    820                                      index=self.index, name=name)

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Comment: Can you share the code with which you attempted to replace `A` with the variable it receives from iterating through the table, so we can reproduce (and then more easily debug) your error?  Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @MaxvonHippel Edited, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hmm, have you tried re-indexing `prices`, or dropping the index on `prices`? I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45727478/1586231) where the problem was indexing into differently shaped series.